# sorting strings in Java based on substrings

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, comparator

I have a list of strings **def123, abc999, zzz000, abc123, zzz111**.
I want the list sorted such that first three characters are sorted in ascendng order and next three in descending.
So the output should be **abc999, abc123, def123, zzz111,zzz000**
Is this possible?

Comment: Everything is possible, but SO if you want help you need to show some attempt to solve the problem. So I'll point you in the right direction. You need to implement Comparable, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property

Comment: Comparable does not fit here, since Strings are final.

Comment: (`Comparable does not fit here, since Strings are final` - applies  _if_ `string` from the question is `java.lang.String`. (Then, there are things like [AspectJ](http://eclipse.org/aspectj)…).)

Answer (score 7):

Other answers have suggested you implement `Comparator`. That's no longer necessary with recent utility methods added to the interface in Java 8:

```
list.sort(Comparator
    .comparing(s -> s.substring(0, 3))
    .thenComparing(s -> s.subtring(3, 6), Comparator.reverseOrder()));
```

Also note that `List` now has a `sort` method.

Comment: This one needs and ending parenthesis. Even if I enter that, this one is giving me compiler errors. any idea??

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. You will have to write your own `Comparator`.  Here's a tutorial to get you started https://www.tutorialspoint.com//java/java_using_comparator.htm

Comment: That tutorial is now very out-of-date. Java 8's enhancements to Comparator means that it is generally not necessary to override `compare`. Having said that, Oracle's tutorial on building comparators is equally out-of-date!

Answer (score 2):

Break the strings into two substrings and then sort using `comparator`.  Something like this: [Demo](http://ideone.com/Wr6kkY)

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("def123", "abc999", "zzz000", "abc123", "zzz111");

Comparator<String> cmp = new Comparator<String>() {
  public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
    int diff = (o1.substring(0,3)).compareTo(o2.substring(0,3));
        return (diff == 0) ? (Integer.valueOf(o2.substring(3)).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o1.substring(3)))): diff;
  }
};
Collections.sort(list, cmp);
```

Comment: I like sprinter suggested solution more...+1 to him...:)

Comment: In this special case, where the source strings have equal lengths with leading zeros where necessary, you can just compare the strings without parsing them to `int`s.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom class including your `String` as an attribute. That class should implement the [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface.

Inside your custom class you have to override method `compareTo(T o)` which was inherited from `Comparable` interface. You should apply your sorting logic there.

Then if you make a `Collection` (ex: `List<CustomClass>`) using that custom class as the object type, you can use Collections.sort(list) method to sort that List.

A complete example can be found [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com//java/java_using_comparator.htm).

Answer (score -1):

If you want more of an algorithmic approach, check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/5adpqgrc/1/

```
// start with ['def123', 'abc999', 'zzz000', 'abc123', 'zzz111']
var strings = ['def123', 'abc999', 'zzz000', 'abc123', 'zzz111']
$('body').append(strings.join(' ') + '<br>')

// reverse the digits
// get this ['def876', 'abc000', 'zzz999', 'abc876', 'zzz888']
strings = reverse_digits_only(strings)
$('body').append(strings.join(' ') + '<br>')

// sort it
// get this ['abc000', 'abc876', 'def876', 'zzz888', 'zzz999']
strings = strings.sort()
$('body').append(strings.join(' ') + '<br>')

// reverse the digits again
// get this ['abc999' 'abc123' 'def123' 'zzz111' 'zzz000']
strings = reverse_digits_only(strings)
$('body').append(strings.join(' ') + '<br>')


function reverse_digits_only (strings) {
    return strings.map(function (string) {
        var first_three_letters = string.substring(0, 3)
        var reversed_digits = string.substring(3).split('').map(function (digit) {
            return 9 - digit
        })

        return first_three_letters + reversed_digits.join('')
    })
}
```

How this works is that you:

1. Reverse the digits (abc999 becomes abc000)
2. Then sort it naturally
3. And then reverse the digits again.

Comment: this is **javascript** not **java**